# Django Logging: django.db.backends returns "(0.000) None; args=None" message

Tags: django-logging

I'm trying to log my database queries using Django Logging, but the log message seems to be void. I'm using Django 2.1, Python 3.6, with MySQL database.

My `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': SITE_ROOT + '/mylog.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

Resulting log:

```
2019-02-07 11:27:17,642 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.000) None; args=None
2019-02-07 11:27:17,642 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.000) None; args=None
2019-02-07 11:27:17,643 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.000) None; args=(2,)
2019-02-07 11:27:17,657 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.000) None; args=(2,)
2019-02-07 11:27:17,670 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.000) None; args=(2,)
2019-02-07 11:27:17,843 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.165) None; args=(2, 2, 2)
```

How can I have the SQL queries?

Comment: Your LOGGING dictionary is set correctly. The problem is something else. Is your application running on `DEBUG=False`?

Comment: No, I have `DEBUG = True`

Answer (score 3):

Slightly late to the party, but I just ran into this issue and found a resolution on django-debug-toolbar's GitHub page about this specific issue. Apparently `mysqlclient==1.3.14` might be the culprit, and using a different version of it (I tried 1.3.12 and 1.4.4) solved this problem for me.

Comment: `pip install mysqlclient==1.4.4` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

It's definitely a problem with mysqlclient.

I was using django  1.11.6 Which is an old «patch» version.

I just tried to upgrade django with the latest 1.11.x, the 1.11.29 and the bug is here as well

So upgrading Django doesn't fix the bug, it isn't fixed in 1.11.x branch of django

the version 1.4.6 of mysqlclient is the last version that doesn't have the issue, on both 1.11.6 and 1.11.29

I created the issue https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/441

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed already. Upgrade your Django.
See https://github.com/django/django/pull/10726